# How to keep docker container up?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I created a docker container where I install mariadb-server and some more stuff (see screen), but now I want to keep the container running of course, so people can connect to the database server in the container.

The problem is that the container keeps exiting after completed running.
In the last row of the screen you see i tried adding a tail -f, but that also didn't help.

These are the commands I use for building and running:

```
sudo docker build -t databaseserver .
sudo docker run -it -p 3306:3306 databaseserver
```

Please help me to just keep it running so i can connect to the running container

[image: Screen of Dockerfile]

[image: screen of start-up.sh]

Comment: Have you tried to use `docker logs`? I strongly suspect that your container is crashing.

Comment: @Fang the logs look fine

Comment: A general comment unrelated to your problem:  you should move most of 'start-up.sh' to the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4):

You should move much of startup.sh into the Dockerfile.

Then instead of calling `service mysql start` which starts it in 'daemon mode', you should figure out how to start it interactively.

Then you would not have to tail the logs to keep the container from closing.

At that point you could invoke docker in daemon mode or interactively (your choice) and it should just work right.

Comment: What can stay in start-up.sh then?

Comment: In Dockerfile: install and configure the database.  startup.sh should only start up the database.  Ur problem is you are starting the db using 'service mysql start' which starts mysql,in another process.  As soon as startup.sh finishes the container and all child processes including ur database stop.

Comment: A simple, easy but unelegant solution to ur problem is to replace 'tail - f ...' with 'sleep infinity'

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try running the container in daemon mode instead of interactive mode.

So your command should be:

sudo docker run -d -p 3306:3306 databaseserver

Comment: it keeps up for 30 seconds, and after that it exits automatically

Comment: I think in daemon mode the 'tail -f' fails and 30 seconds is about how long it takes to get to that failure.

Answer (score 0):

CMD `servcie mysql start` in start-up.sh is async,
`mysql -u root < /honepot-project/Database/info.sql` may exec failed and exit.

Comment: but i see in the logs that it works and when i execute a select query on the database, i see the tables are inserted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Put the tail -f /dev/null in the dockerfile.

Comment: I suspect this would cause build to fail.  If it did not fail it would take forever.

Answer (score 0):

Do it how the MySQL image in the Docker library does it:

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/3362baccb4352bcf0022014f67c1ec7e6808b8c5/8.0/Dockerfile

The last line of the Dockerfile is:

```
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

This will keep the container running (assuming it starts and doesn't stop for any reason), and output any error messages to the logs.